# Help ID SMD components

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image: RVG sensor board]

I need some help correctly identifying the U9 and U10 components on the PCB. I've tried some codebooks and I found several options.

For U9:

H1 - X6603 is a 300mA, low quiescent, high PSRR, low noise and low dropout linear
regulator, but the model marked with "Lv" is a 4.7V and this board is a 3.3V

H2 - Toshiba 200 mA CMOS Low Drop-Out Regulator with Fast Load Transient Response TCR2EF series, but Pin 4 is connected to capacitor C46 and it should be NC...

For U10:

H1 - "4FD" - in the 2011 edition of the active smd components guide, it's a FT521FDa, LDO, Dual out, Vout1/Vout2=2.7V/1.8V±2%, 250mA, +CE, but again it should be 3.3V (4FJ).

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your U10 is a [Microchip 24FC256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21203m.pdf) - spot the logo in the pin-4 corner?

I suspect that your U9 *might* be a [Linear technology LTC1663](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1663fd.pdf).
The pin connections for VCC(pin-4) and GND(pin-2) are almost certainly correct, making C46 its decoupling cap.

Comment: Yes, you're right, measurements match! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly right, sometimes we miss out the obvious... Thank you very much for your effort and support.